# PGSQL - Translate query results with foreign keys

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg

I have two tables that describe items and products:

Category:

```
| categoryid   | categoryname     |
| -------------| -----------------|
| 1            | "a"              |
| 2            | "b"              |
```

Item:

```
| itemid   | itemname      |
| -------- | --------------|
| 1        | "c"           |
| 2        | "d"           |
| 3        | "e"           |
```

and a third table to map them together:

ItemToCategory:

```
| itemid   | categoryid     |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | 1              |
| 2        | 2              |
| 3        | 2              |
```

What's the best way to create a query that returns the itemname and categoryname of all itemnames in array '[c,d]':

```
| itemname | categoryname  |
| -------- | --------------|
| "c"      | "a"           |
| "d"      | "b"           |
```

Comment: Are item and category the wrong way around at the top of your question? Also, I assume a category can contain more than one item? If it's a straight 1-1 mapping then probably best to just stick it all in 1 table.

Comment: Yeah I edited, mixed them up. 1 category can have multiple items.

Comment: Do you want a JSON array? Because `{c,d}` typically represents an object, not an array.

Comment: Nono I would like an actual array [c,d], as '{c,d}' is the right syntax to enter arrays in pg i thought that's the way to write it. So to sum up i would like the itemname+catrgoryname of all items with itemname "c" or itemname "d".

Comment: @TheImpaler: `{c,d}` is the text representation of a native Postgres array. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=88d58a73e508877635bacf3965c97ba7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANY operator in a WHERE clause to achieve this:

```
select i.itemname, c.categoryname 
from item i
  join itemtocategory ic on ic.itemid = i.itemid
  join category c on c.categoryid = ic.categoryid
where i.itemname = any(array['c', 'd'])
```

The condition `= any(array['c', 'd'])` is equivalent to `IN ('c', 'd')`